# Using linux root libraries in windows

Tags: c#, c++, root-framework

I have to work with c++ libraries based on ROOT cern. These libraries were written with Linux environment and k dev and now I have to use these libraries in windows with Visual Studio. First I am just trying to compile some headers .h and some source codes .cpp in Visual c++ to create a dll. these files compiled without any problem in Linux.

So I have a problem generating a working DLL that I can use later in csharp.

The errors i am getting are LNK errors even though I believe I added the necessary .lib in the linker wich are libraries related to ROOT.

The errors are the following :

```
Error 1 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall Directory::ShowMembers(class TMemberInspector &)" (?ShowMembers@Directory@@UAEXAAVTMemberInspector@@@Z) 

Error 2 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall Directory::Streamer(class TBuffer &)" (?Streamer@Directory@@UAEXAAVTBuffer@@@Z) 

Error 3 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class TClass * __cdecl Directory::Class(void)" (?Class@Directory@@SAPAVTClass@@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual class TClass * __thiscall Directory::IsA(void)const " (?IsA@Directory@@UBEPAVTClass@@XZ)
```

I'd really appreciate if someone could point to some hints!

Comment: Yes, it is not clear from your question whether you are trying to compile the ROOT libraries or a program that uses them.

Comment: have you tried compiling ROOT libraries with cygwin or mingw? what does ROOT website says about this platform/compiler?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. You have to re-compile those libraries on Windows if you have source code. Otherwise ask the vendor for a Windows version.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links that might be useful for you.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-create-files-needed-to-build-and-use-dlls-under-linux/

http://www.kegel.com/crosstool/

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to browse on the source of those libraries (not a problem, since ROOT is open source) and find the definitions for those methods. It might sound obvious, but it seems those functions are supposed to be defined elsewhere